# PHP POST serialize() data from dynamic form ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a script on jQuery and HTML5 that creates a form dynamically.

Then I use:

```
var OForm = $('#OForm');

// Find disabled inputs, and remove the "disabled" attribute
var disabled = OForm.find(':input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');

// serialize the form
var Values = OForm.serialize();

// re-disabled the set of inputs that you previously enabled
disabled.attr('disabled','disabled');

console.log(Values);
```

Then I use ajax to POST the Values to PHP.

Problem:

If the form was not dynamic. I can get the values:

```
$name = $_POST['name']
```

and so on..

But the problem is that I have some fields in my form that are numbered.

Example:

- name1
- name2
- name3

or can also be:

- name3
- name10
- name23

How can I get these values to insert them on MySQL?

**SOLVED**

Use arrays instead of numbered keys.

```
<input name="name[10]" value="Josh"><input name="name[23]" value="Peter">
```

Submitted:

```
$_POST["name"] = array(
    "10" => "Josh",
    "23" => "Peter",
);
```

You can use foreach to traverse all names:

```
foreach ($_POST["name"] as $key => $value) {}
```

Comment: why dont you use an array? `<input type="text" name="name[]">`

Comment: I don't think I understant your solution. The form is already generated and the field names are generated depending on the number of fields.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you are refereing to the element name not the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrays instead of numbered keys.

```
<input name="name[10]" value="Josh"><input name="name[23]" value="Peter">
```

Submitted:

```
$_POST["name"] = array(
    "10" => "Josh",
    "23" => "Peter",
);
```

You can use foreach to traverse all names:

```
foreach ($_POST["name"] as $key => $value) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I use the same name="name[]" to diffent elements? to create an array of different inputs?

Comment: If you want to number them automatically, you can use `name="name[]"`, php will generate zero-based array.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But for each person I have name and age. Can I create an array like 0 - Joao - 16 / 1 - Anna - 23?

Comment: You can use two arrays and combine them in php (`name="name[]"` and `name="age[]"`) or generate indexes in javascript (`name="person[1][name]"` and `name="person[1][age]"`). You **can't** use auto-generated indexes in the second approach (`name="person[][name]"` and `name="person[][age]"`) because the array will be `$_POST["person"] = array(0 => array("name" => "value"), 1 => array("age" => "value"))`.

Comment: Perfect! What approach is the best for you?

Comment: If I can ensure that every `name[]` has its own `age[]`, I personally prefer combining in php (`name="name[]"` and `name="age[]"`).

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I cannot ensure that. If I can I'll use array_merge() or array_combine() if not I'll try to do the indexes in javascript.